# hexagonal ball with internal structure

Tags: modeling

please tell me how you can get such a model

[image]

with the possibility of setting different sizes of hexagons and, accordingly, their number.

I've already figured out how to create a hexagonal sphere using a Tissue Addon and a grid modifier. The question is whether it is now possible to get a model as in the first figure. Inset faces leads to bad results (file *.blend https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fkA9pqOhGIKLMQMdFVtmHcSwSyt_HLNI/view?usp=share_link)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the Inset doesn't work for you because the tissue workflow might result in not-so-clean geometry. You could try this addon:
[image]

[image]

[image]

In *Edit Mode*, select all and hit **I** (Inset) and **I** again for *Inset Individual Faces*.

[image]

Then hit **I** again to inset another time, and with the last inset faces still selected, hit **S** to scale down:

[image]

Comment: 1. For insetting individual faces, you don't need to set the _Pivot Point_ to _Individual Origins_. And for scaling them later you need _Median Point_ or else you could have simply inset them further. 2. Your method does work with symmetrical shapes that can be scaled down to a _Median Point_, with irregular shapes this will be problematic. There I would use a second insetting while holding Ctrl to create depth, then release Ctrl to change the inset size. Or later scale down, this time with _Individual Origins_.

Comment: Good point. I have removed the *Individual Origins* from my post. Also, you are right about the limited use when dealing with irregular shapes. Thanks for the hint with the inset depth (Ctrl) - Didn't know that one! ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I always think Inset is a very underrated tool :-)

Answer (score 2):

Inset works as expected.

1. (Duplicate your mesh first.)
2. Merge by a small distance <kbd>m</kbd>. Make faces <kbd>f</kbd>.
3. Inset. (**Make sure *individual faces* is turned ON.**)
4. Inset again. (Hold Ctrl to extrude the faces inwards.)

[image: inset edges]

Comment: Instead of extruding and shrink/fatten you could simply hit I again, hold Ctrl to move inwards, then release Ctrl to change the size.

Comment: Updated. Numbers of steps seems to stay the same, though.

Comment: This was more for general solutions, Shrink/Fatten might give problems with more irregular shapes. And by the way, when you merge by distance, the vertices are not all merged at their center, so the shape becomes a bit asymmetrical.